# Query method should return Cursor or List ? (Mongo DB C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I have a task in which I need to query a large amount of data. I created a method for the queries:

```
public List<T> Query(FilterDefinition<T> filter, SortDefinition<T> sort, int limit)
{
    var query = Collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(limit);
    var result = query.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

In the main method:

```
List<Cell> cells = MyDatabaseService.Query(filter, sort, 100000);
```

This List will contain 100000 values which is quite large.

On the other hand I can also use:

```
public async Task<IAsyncCursor<T>> QueryAsync(FilterDefinition<T> filter, SortDefinition<T> sort, int limit)
{
    FindOptions<T> options = new FindOptions<T> { Sort = sort, Limit = limit };
    var queryCursor =  await Collection.FindAsync(filter, options);
    return queryCursor;
}
```

In the main, then I use a while loop to iterate the cursor.

```
Task<IAsyncCursor<Cell>> cursor = MyDatabaseService.QueryAsync(filter, sort, 100000);
while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
{
    var batch = queryCursor.Current;
    foreach (var document in batch)
    {

    }
}
```

So considering I have a lot of data to query, is it a good idea to use the 2nd implementation ? Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you are planning to do with the documents once you've retrieved them from the server.

If you need to perform an operation that requires all 100,000 documents to be in the program's memory then the two methods will essentially do the same thing.

On the other hand, if you are using the returned documents one by one, the second method is better: the first will essentially process every document twice (once to retrieve it along with all other documents and once to act on it); the second will process it once (retrieve and act immediately).

Comment: By act on it do you mean it will save it to the List ? Also will the first method block the thread ?

Comment: I used the term 'act on it' because I have no idea what you will be doing with the documents once you've retrieved them - will you be rendering them, querying them again, etc? In terms of thread blocking, there is a `ToListAsync` method on `IFindFluent` which will stop thread blocking